# Can disable select box but can't select first child with similar code

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a combobox that I disable when user clicks on checkbox with this:

```
$(this).parent().next('td').children('.xyz').attr("disabled", true);
```

I would also like to reset the same combobox to display the first value on the list, using this:

```
$(this).parent().next('td').children('.xyz option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected");
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using tables? Make proper selectors, not cell childs.

Comment: checkbox+combobox are displayed as a table, yes. Elements do have individual ids and I can use them, but I would like to know why this method doesn't work.

Comment: [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) Use display:inline and style with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selection with JavaScript is a bit different. It'll be easier to use this plugin, from [this discussion](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/cannot-set-selected-selected-via-attr-on-option-elements):

```
/**
 * Select/deselect any matching checkboxes, radio buttons or option elements.
 */
$.fn.selected = function(select) {
    if (select == undefined) select = true;
    return this.each(function() {
        var t = this.type;
        if (t == 'checkbox' || t == 'radio')
            this.checked = select;
        else if (this.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'option') {
            var $sel = $(this).parent('select');
            if (select && $sel[0] && $sel[0].type == 'select-one') {
                // deselect all other options
                $sel.find('option').selected(false);
            }
            this.selected = select;
        }
    });
};
```

and

```
$(this).parent().next('td').children('.xyz option:first-child').selected(true);
```

Comment: minitech, doesn't seem to work. I am sure the method is right, but the problem is that when selector has 'option:first-child', no object gets selected (according to console, at least).

Comment: @Nikita: Try `option:first-of-type`.